# How to apply parameter expansion on brace expansion (range)?

Tags: bash, syntax, brace-expansion, parameter-expansion

I would like to apply [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) (e.g. search and replace) in order to remove spaces from the [brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace?s[]=ranges#ranges) (`{a..z}`). It is possible?

So I've the following range: `{a..z}` which consist all letters and I would like to remove spaces in one go.

Here is longer example:

```
$ echo {a..z}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
$ az=$(eval echo {a..z})
$ echo $az
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
$ echo ${az// /}
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Is it possible to apply parameter expansion directly on a range? Or at least to make it in one expression, especially without assigning this to variable?

---

One example usage is to specify all parameters dynamically for `getopts`, for example:

```
while getopts {a..z} arg; do
  printf $arg
done
```

however this doesn't work (e.g. `./az.sh -a -b -c`) as spaces from that range needs to be removed first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
$ printf '%s' {a..z}; echo
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

And this if you need to use a var (bash):

```
$ printf -v var '%s' {a..z}
$ echo "$var"
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

---

Parameter expansion only could be applied to a Parameter (hence it's name).
So no, you could not apply "Parameter expansion" to a "Brace Expansion".
It must be in two steps:

```
var="$(printf '%s ' {a..z})"
var="${var// /}"
```

So `getopts` example would look like:

```
while getopts "$(printf '%s' {a..z})" arg; do
  printf '%s' "$arg"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ set {m..z} && IFS=, && echo "$*"
m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
$ set {m..z} && IFS='' && echo "$*"
mnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: Session-global modification of `IFS` for a local effect.

Comment: Also overwriting the current positional parameters without saving them.

Comment: `(declare -a f=({a..z});IFS=;echo "${f[*]}")`. But the printf solution is better.